# Find all index position in list based on partial string inside item in list

Tags: python, list, substring, enumerate

```
mylist = ["aa123", "bb2322", "aa354", "cc332", "ab334", "333aa"]
```

I need the index position of all items that contain `'aa'`. I'm having trouble combining `enumerate()` with partial string matching. I'm not even sure if I should be using enumerate.

I just need to return the index positions: 0,2,5

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) inside a [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
indices = [i for i, s in enumerate(mylist) if 'aa' in s]
```

Comment: how can you make this be case insensitive?

Comment: @abbood - By comparing to `s.lower()`

Comment: what if I just want to get single index for the first match only?

Comment: @shashwat - You don't have to use the generator expression in the brackets to created a list. You can use it to create a generator `gen = ()` which you then call `next` on.

Comment: if you could please give an example for how I use this? I am completely new to Python.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I am fairly new to python. Could you provide a simple explanation how  read you code 
indices = [i for i, s in enumerate(mylist) if 'aa' in s]
Or could you write the code in different way?

Comment: It does not run if there are NA's. How to consider this case?

Answer (score 24):

Your idea to use `enumerate()` was correct.

```
indices = []
for i, elem in enumerate(mylist):
    if 'aa' in elem:
        indices.append(i)
```

Alternatively, as a list comprehension:

```
indices = [i for i, elem in enumerate(mylist) if 'aa' in elem]
```

Comment: How might the list comprehension get extended to instead of "if 'aa'"  to be "if ["aa","bb"] in elem" ??

Comment: @GrantRWHumphries You go one level lower with second for loop: `indices = [i for i, elem in enumerate(mylist) if any(a in elem for a in ["aa","bb"])]`.

Answer (score 12):

Without `enumerate()`:

```
>>> mylist = ["aa123", "bb2322", "aa354", "cc332", "ab334", "333aa"]
>>> l = [mylist.index(i) for i in mylist if 'aa' in i]
>>> l
[0, 2, 5]
```

Comment: This is likely to run in O(n^2), whereas using enumerate will be O(n).

Comment: This will return a wrong result if one of the strings containing 'aa' is duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this answer, I'd like to show how to *"early exit"* the iteration once the **first item** containing the substring `aa` is encountered. This only returns the **first position**.

```
import itertools
first_idx = len(tuple(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: "aa" not in x, mylist)))
```

This should be **much more performant** than looping over the whole list **when the list is large**, since `takewhile` will stop once the condition is `False` for the first time.

I know that the question asked for *all* positions, but since there will be many users stumbling upon this question when searching for the *first* substring, I'll add this answer anyways.

Answer (score -4):

```
spell_list = ["Tuesday", "Wednesday", "February", "November", "Annual", "Calendar", "Solstice"]

index=spell_list.index("Annual")
print(index)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. A value error will be thrown when you use this method but only specifies list.index('an'). The method will be unable to find annual.

Comment: Right. This is an incorrect answer to the question that has been asked.