# Return index position in array based on a partial string in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, indexing, partial

Suppose you have an array `p`:

```
p=[['0', '9', '10', '13'], ['1', '8', '10', '14'], 
   ['2', '7', '9', '15'], ['3', '2', '8',  '18'], 
   ['4', '1', '7', '19'], ['5', '1', '2', '20'], 
   ['6', '2', '4', '21'], ['7', '1', '3',  '22'], 
   ['8', '4', '6', '25'], ['9', '3', '5', '26'], 
   ['10', '5', '6', '27'], ['11', '8', '10', '28'],
   ['12', '7', '9', '31'], ['13', '1', '2', '32'], 
   ['14', '4', '6', '33'], ['15', '3', '5', '34']]
```

I am interested in knowing the indexes of elements based on a partial string that should  always match with elements in `p` at positions `[1]` and `[2]` (In `p` that would be `9,10`, `8,10`, `7,9`, `2,8` etc). For example, I would like to know the indexes of elements containing the partial string `'1','2'`. In such case, the indexes should be: `[5,13]` that corresponds to elements:

```
    ['5', '1', '2', '20']
    ['13', '1', '2', '32']
```

I found this related question in stackoverflow: [python - find index postion in list based of partial string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849293/python-find-index-postion-in-list-based-of-partial-string). However, when I have tried with only `2` as the partial string I have got the following result (which is perfect):

```
    >>> indices = [i for i, s in enumerate(p) if '2' in s]
    >>> indices
     [2, 3, 5, 6, 13]
    >>>
```

But then, if I try with `('1','2')` I get nothing:

```
    >>> indices = [i for i, s in enumerate(p) if ('1','2') in s]
    >>> indices
     []
```

How should I write the partial string in the `if` so that this code work?. I really don't understand why it is not working. I'd be happy if somebody could help me to understand this. I have tried: putting the partial string between `[]`, define it as an array before the conditional and that doesn't work either. Is there another way to accomplish the same task?, because I am aware that the mere use of the code presented in the link mentioned above does not search matches in positions `[1]` and `[2]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
indices = [i for i, s in enumerate(p) if ('1','2') == (s[1],s[2])]
```

In your list comprehension, each `s` is an array of strings, and the if statement is checking whether a tuple of two strings is contained in that list, which always evaluates to false.

```
>>> '2' in ['5', '1', '2', '20']
True
>>> ('1', '2') in ['5', '1', '2', '20']
False
>>> ['1', '2'] in ['5', '1', '2', '20']
False
```

This is why the resulting `indices` is empty.

Comment: @muammar No problem. You can consider closing this question by accepting the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `itertool.combinations` like in this example:

```
import itertools

indices = [i for i, s in enumerate(p) if ('1', '2') in list(itertools.combinations(s, 2))]
print indices
```

and the output will be :

```
[5, 13]
```

knowing that using `list`over itertools uses lots of memory if you have big list.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not sure how much memory itertools will take when the lists will get bigger. So I am taking as answer the one provided by @YS-L.