# Find index position in list based on more than one partial string and using operator in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, indexing, partial

Suppose you have a list `mylist`

```
mylist = ["aa123", "bb2322", "aa354", "cc332", "ab334", "333aa"]
```

how to find an index for element that have both 'aa' and '3'? I expect the value returned to 0  "aa123", 2 "aa354", 4 "ab334" and 5 "333aa".

there are some similar thread in stack overflow:  [Find all index position in list based on partial string inside item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849293/find-all-index-position-in-list-based-on-partial-string-inside-item-in-list) and [Return index position in array based on a partial string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201414/return-index-position-in-array-based-on-a-partial-string-in-python).

But when I tried to use 'and' but it returned to all index

```
mylist = ["aa123", "bb2322", "aa354", "cc332", "ab334", "333aa"]
l = [i for i, s in enumerate(mylist) if ('aa' and '3') in s]
print(l)

output : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Thanks so much in advance, I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. The problem with your code is in `if` statement, `('aa' and '3')` is evaluating as `'3'` which is present in each element of your list. You can check this by printing the output of `print('aa' and '3')`. Modify your `if` statement as below:

```
mylist = ["aa123", "bb2322", "aa354", "cc332", "ab334", "333aa"]
idx = [i for i, s in enumerate(mylist) if "aa" in s and "3" in s]
print(idx)
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 5]
```