# Find the list indices of all occurrences of a substring within the list

Tags: python, list, substring

I'm using Python 3.10. I have an incredibly large list. Each item in the list is 26 character string. Somewhere within this vast list is a name. I would like to return the list indices of all occurrences of this name, which is a substring within a string.

It's a simple list called `alphabet`, with just one entry at each index. Every entry is a string and what I'm looking for is a string. Everything is in uppercase and no special characters are involved.

I've looked at several things but I'm only able to find results for returning substrings within strings. It's the fact that it's in a list that is stumping me...

Comment: An exact duplicate: [Find all index position in list based on partial string inside item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14849293/6045800)

Comment: Just curious: how large is "incredibly" large, and what does the size matter?

Comment: @Tomerikoo. You're right, I apologise. I'm still learning but need to be better with searches. My mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
indices = [idx for idx, s in enumerate(alphabet) if name in s]
```

where `alphabet` is your list of strings, and `name` is the desired substring.

Comment: Hi there. The name is a substring within a string... You answered before I could edit, I apologise.