# Get multiple column value based on partial matching with another column value for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following dataframe:

```
URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF = pd.DataFrame(data=[{'main_url': 'http://keilstruplund.dk', 'emails': ['ole.norlin@mail.dk', 'ole.gregersen@hk.dk', 'prima-rent@youseepost.dk', 'jb@rentind.dk', 'frisoren01@gmail.com','stigterndrup@gmail.com', 'psn@psn.dk', 'samuel@malerfirmaet-lykkebo.dk', 'jan@mundt-reklame.dk',  'nordsjalland@phonixtag.dk', 'jp@rudersdalmaleren.dk', 'vvs@hestetangen.dk', 'steenkragelund@mail.tele.dk', 'kasserer@keilstruplund.dk']},                                        
                                 {'main_url': 'http://kirsebaergaarden.com', 'emails': ['info@kirsebaergaarden.com','ghost1054@yahoo.com']},
                                 {'main_url': 'http://koglernes.dk', 'emails': ['info@koglernes.dk']},
                                  {'main_url': 'http://kongehojensbornehave.dk', 'emails': []}
                               ])
```

However, I want to keep only those values for property named "emails" whose every element's value after '@' is same as the corresponding value of the 'main_url' property but after "http://" resulting the following data frame:

```
URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF = pd.DataFrame(data=[{'main_url': 'http://keilstruplund.dk', 'emails': ['kasserer@keilstruplund.dk']},                                        
                                 {'main_url': 'http://kirsebaergaarden.com', 'emails': ['info@kirsebaergaarden.com']},
                                 {'main_url': 'http://koglernes.dk', 'emails': ['info@koglernes.dk']},
                                  {'main_url': 'http://kongehojensbornehave.dk', 'emails': []}
                               ])
```

[image]

Any hints or approach is appreciable considering the fact that I have millions row to implement the transformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try I think it should be able to handle a few millions of rows.

```
def list_check(emails_list, email_match):
    match_indexes = [i for i, s in enumerate(emails_list) if email_match in s]
    return [emails_list[index] for index in match_indexes]

# Parse main_url to get domain column
df['domain'] = list(map(lambda x: x.split('//')[1], df['main_url']))

# Apply list_check to your dataframe using emails and domain columns
df['emails'] = list(map(lambda x, y: list_check(x, y), df['emails'], df['domain']))

# Drop domain column
df.drop(columns=['domain'], inplace=True)
```

`list_check` function checks whether your match string is in the emails list and gets indexes of matches, then gets values from the emails list using matched indexes and returns those values in a list.

Output:

[image: output df]

[source for getting matched indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14849322/12558096)

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to make it work as I do not have any separate column named "domain". also the domain name should extracted from the main_url values. Thanks for the try :)

Comment: ah of course, forgot to add it.
edit: added it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to `explode` the `mails` column then compare with `main_url` column

```py
df_ = URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF.explode('emails').reset_index()
m = (df_['main_url'].str.split('//').str[1] == df_['emails'].str.split('@').str[1])
df_ = df_[m].groupby('main_url').agg({'emails':lambda x: list(x)})
```

```
print(df_)
                                                  emails
main_url
http://keilstruplund.dk      [kasserer@keilstruplund.dk]
http://kirsebaergaarden.com  [info@kirsebaergaarden.com]
http://koglernes.dk                  [info@koglernes.dk]
```

At last, map the result to original dataframe

```py
URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF['matched'] = URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF['main_url'].map(df_['emails']).fillna("").apply(list)
```

```
print(URL_WITH_EMAILS_DF[['main_url', 'matched']])

                         main_url                      matched
0         http://keilstruplund.dk  [kasserer@keilstruplund.dk]
1     http://kirsebaergaarden.com  [info@kirsebaergaarden.com]
2             http://koglernes.dk          [info@koglernes.dk]
3  http://kongehojensbornehave.dk                           []
```

Comment: When its millions of row, how is your answer better performance wise?

Comment: @ShihabUllah Have no idea.